# aap - python trouble

Tags: python, linux

i'm trying to run aap-application. Version is 1.076 (tried higher). All commands send me an error like:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "/usr/bin/aap", line 10, in
> <module>
>     import Main   File "/usr/share/aap/Main.py", line 14, in
> <module>
>     from DoAddDef import doadddef   File "/usr/share/aap/DoAddDef.py",
> line 10, in <module>
>     from Action import find_primary_action   File
> "/usr/share/aap/Action.py", line 30,
> in <module>
>     from Dictlist import listitem2str, str2dictlist, dictlist2str   File
> "/usr/share/aap/Dictlist.py", line 18,
> in <module>
>     from Process import recipe_error   File "/usr/share/aap/Process.py", line
> 13, in <module>
>     from Work import setrpstack   File "/usr/share/aap/Work.py", line 25, in
> <module>
>     from Node import Node   File "/usr/share/aap/Node.py", line 10, in
> <module>
>     import Filetype   File "/usr/share/aap/Filetype.py", line
> 1417
>     as = 0
>      ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What problem could it be?

Comment: You need to use Python 2.5 or under.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that it works with Python 2.6 or older - [see this thread on aap mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=200904062015.n36KFPf3030585%40moolenaar.net&forum_name=a-a-p-develop)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, `as` is a reserved word in Python.  So, that can't be used in FileType.py as a variable name.

Try updating your installation of `aap` or writing in to the aap authors/forums.

Comment: I used different versions of software. Okay, i'll send message to developers

Answer (score 3):

`as` is a [reserved word](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) in Python.

Seems aap-application was written for Python 2.5 and bellow:

> Changed in version 2.5: Both **`as`** and `with` are only recognized when the `with_statement` future feature has been
>   enabled. **It will always be enabled in
>   Python 2.6**. See section The with
>   statement for details. Note that using
>   as and with as identifiers will always
>   issue a warning, even when the
>   `with_statement` future directive is not
>   in effect.